# Calculating mean value of item in several columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with values spread over several columns. I want to calculate the mean value of all items from specific columns.

All the solutions I looked up end up giving me either the separate means of each column or the mean of the means of the selected columns.

E.g. my Dataframe looks like this:

```
Name    a   b   c   d
Alice   1   2   3   4
Alice   2       4   2
Alice   3           2
Alice   1       5   2
Ben     3   3   1   3
Ben     4   1   2   3
Ben     1   2   2
```

And I want to see the mean of the values in columns b & c for each "Alice":

When I try:

```
df[df["Name"]=="Alice"][["b","c"]].mean()
```

The result is:

```
b    2.00
c    4.00
dtype: float64
```

In another post I found a suggestion to try a "double" mean one time for each axis e.g:

```
df[df["Name"]=="Alice"][["b","c"]].mean(axis=1).mean()
```

But the result was then:

```
3.00
```

which is the mean of the means of both columns.

I am expecting a way to calculate:
(2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 4 = 3.50

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's [**`np.nanmean`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) here this will simply see your section of the dataframe as an array, and calculate the mean over the entire section by default:

```
>>> np.nanmean(df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Alice', ['b', 'c']])
3.5
```

Or if you want to group by name, you can first stack the dataframe, like:

```
>>> df[['Name','b','c']].set_index('Name').stack().reset_index().groupby('Name').agg('mean')
              0
Name           
Alice  3.500000
Ben    1.833333
```

Answer (score 4):

Can `groupby` to `sum` all values and get their respective sizes. Then, divide to get the mean.

This way you get for all `Name`s at once.

```
g = df.groupby('Name')[['b', 'c']]
g.sum().sum(1)/g.count().sum(1)
```

---

```
Name
Alice    3.500000
Ben      1.833333
dtype: float64
```

---

PS: In your example, looks like you have empty strings in some cells. That's not advisable, since you'll have `dtypes` set to `object` for your columns. Try to have `NaN`s instead, to take full advantage of vectorized operations.

Answer (score 4):

Assume all your columns are numeric type and empty spaces are `NaN`. A simple `set_index` and `stack` and direct `mean`

```
df.set_index('Name')[['b','c']].stack().mean(level=0)

Out[117]:
Name
Alice    3.500000
Ben      1.833333
dtype: float64
```